# Extract dependencies hierarchy from Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, dependencies, materialized-views

I am trying to extract hierarchies of different objects from Oracle DB. We have bunch of stored procedures and each stored procedures are refreshing multiple MVs or tables. On top of these are built individual views. Each stored procedures are executed through external jobs from ETL. Is there a way i can figure out the hierarchy or chain of the process. For example which stored procedure has what all MVs and what all views are dependent on these MVs/tables? Some thing like below -

Stored Procedures ----> MVs/Tables----Views

I tried with some Oracle tables as below but not able to connect the dots. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Also any other tables i need to look at?

```
select * from all_mview_analysis
select * from all_mview_detail_relations
select * from all_procedures
select * from all_dependencies
```

Comment: those views will do the trick, as long as you don't  have any SQL Dynamic in your procedures. ( example: a variable refers to a table but the table is passed after a query retrieves its name ) Those don't appear in any dictionary view.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez all the above will give stand alone results. How can i get MVs used inside the stored procedure? One stored procedure have multiple views, how do i link the MVs with corresponding stored procedure?

Comment: to get mviews used for an store proctedure, check all_dependencies. It should be there as TABLES. To actually verify that are mviews you need to check against all_mviews

Comment: if you  want I can post an answer with  an example when a procedure uses one table and one materilaized view

Comment: all_dependencies show whether the object is procedure or any other and all_mviews give the mview names. But how do i link both? Basically how do i link the MV with procedure and find out that the MV is actually refreshed by certaim proedure.

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez can you post an answer with an example as suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into use of the START WITH and CONNECT BY clauses of hierarchical queries.  You will leverage these along with the appropriate _DEPENDENCIES table (USER_DEPENDENCIES, ALL_DEPENDENCIES, DBA_DEPENDENCIES, etc.)

Search for info on ORACLE DB HIERARCHICAL QUERIES.